# What is the loop on the finger of my winter gloves for?

Tags: gear, winter, winter-climbing

I have a pair of winter /climbing gloves. Each glove has a small loop on the ring finger, top of the glove. Why? What's it for?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The loop allows the gloves to be hung, on a carabiner for example, such that the fingers point up preventing the gloves filling with rain or snow.

For example, see the manufacturer's description of [these gloves](http://arcteryx.com/product.aspx?language=EN&gender=Mens&model=Venta-SV-Glove):

> Finger-mounted clip-in loop enables gloves to be attached to a carabiner with finger-tips facing up, eliminating snow-fill